# docker-compose for artifactory and mysql images

Tags: mysql, docker, artifactory, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to set up Artifactory pro with MySQL as the storage database.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
artifactory:
   build: artifactory
   links:
      - mysql
mysql:
   image: stain/mysql-for-artifactory
```

And here is artifactory/Dockerfile

```
#Dockerfile for Artifactory Pro
FROM stain/artifactory-with-mysql
ADD ./artifactory.war /tomcat/webapps
```

When I run the command 'docker-compose up' I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.db.DbService org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.AclServiceImpl.dbService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

what am I missing?

Comment: It seems that the `stain/artifactory-with-mysql` image is NOT a mysql image, but an artifactory image. Based on their webpage https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/artifactory-with-mysql/, you still have to provide a separate mysql image and they have a recommendation on the page.

Comment: Thanks, changed the question

Comment: This exception tells you that Artifactory's DB service failed to initialize - this is either a configuration issue (database config resides in `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME\etc\storage.properties`) or docker compose didn't bring the mysql image first - as they mention in their documentation, and that's why Artifactory can't connect to it.